# How to use String in switch?

Tags: java, string, nullpointerexception, switch-statement

IDE throws an `NullPointerException` when I'm trying to do this. I want to have only 2 genders to choose

```
public  String typeOfGender
    {
        switch (typeOfGender)
        {
            case "Male":
                    typeOfGender = "Male";
                    break;
            case "Female":
                    typeOfGender = "Female";
                    break;
            default:
                    System.out.println(" Unrecognized gender." );
        }
    }
```

Comment: The only way this throws an NPE is if `typeOfGender` is `null`.

Comment: initialize typeOfGender =""

Comment: Use an `enum`. `String` values are not type-safe and are easy to misspell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use them often with no problems, example below. The only reason yours would throw that is if you are passing null to it.

```
private string GetMailBody(string regionCode)
{
    switch(regionCode)
    {
        case "qc":
            //Do some stuff
            break;

        default:
            //If not specified, we assume US, so we do that.
            break;
    }

    return "String we should have edited above";
}
```

Comment: and how do i put it in my constructor of this object?

     public Human(int age, int weight, int height, String name, String 
     typeOfGender)
            {
            super();
            this.age = age;
            this.weight = weight;
            this.height = height;
            this.name = name;
            this.typeOfGender = typeOfGender;
    }


because it shows me "cannot resolve symbol"

Comment: This site http://www.java2novice.com/java_constructor_examples/constructor_with_parameters/ has a good example of constructors. You could simply add it to that.  (The code you pasted wasn't formatted and I don't have access to format it right now).

Comment: Oracle also has an article on using strings in switches. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/strings-switch.html

Comment: Separate question about constructors. Please show your code. Include enough in your example for us to recreate what you saw.

Answer (score 1):

You have not initialized typeOfGender. It is null. That is why. Try

```
typeOfGender="Male";
```

By the way your code does not make sense. If typeOfGender equals "Male", you assign "Male" to it??

Comment: I'm thinking that they only do that for an example.

Answer (score 0):

The `NullPointerExeption` is caused because your string is `null`.

However, for future reference, here's an example of as switch-case with a string:

```
    String string = "foo";
    switch (string) {
        case "foo":
            System.out.println("foo");
            break;
        case "bar":
            System.out.println("bar");
            break;
        default:
            System.out.println("Mushroom Stew!");
            break;
    }
```